# Different display of the element depending on the css selector

Tags: css

Hello guys I have this:

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="left">
  <h1>We're<br> <span>coming<br> soon</span></h1>
  <p>Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store. 
  Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.</p>
  <form action="#">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Adress" maxlength="33" required>
    <button type="submit"><img src="./images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="submit"></button>
    <p class="text-err">Please provide a valid email</p>
    <img src="./images/icon-error.svg" class="error-icon" alt="error">
  </form>    
</div>
```

Why the element class "text-err" it seems to behave differently if I select it in css through ".container left form text-err" instead of only ".text-err"?
I cannot understand, aren't these two different ways to select the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: ".container left form text-err" this is missing the dots to select classes, is that a typo or actual code used?

Answer (score 0):

When you select something directly like `.text-err` it has lower specificity than selecting it via descendant selector like `.container .left form .text-err`.

When there are overriding styles then the style with higher specificity is applied.

You can read more about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this!

Comment: @simonemarketti if this helped you consider accepting the answer to help the community.